# Programmable Bluetooth router

Tags: router, bluetooth, internet-of-things

I previously posted this on Stack Overflow but moved the post here because I feel this forum is more relevant.

I am looking for some kind of hardware that I can buy that has multiple Bluetooth radios, which would allow me to simultaneously connect to multiple Bluetooth-enabled devices. I also need the device to be programmable in a mainstream language like Java or C, so that I can write my own software onto it. However, low-level languages that are easy to learn are also acceptable.

The reason I am looking for this is that I want to create a sort of "hub" for multiple Bluetooth devices, but I do not want to use a pre-made router that has its own packaging (don't want to pay for the extra garbage) and I don't want to have to forcefully update its firmware to edit the software.

I have heard of the raspberry pi, but I don't know if this would be a suitable device to use for multiple connections. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Have you considered just buying multiple USB bluetooth sticks and a powered USB hub.  Plug it into any thing with a USB port including a raspberry pi.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/931188/how-many-devices-can-be-hooked-up-to-one-pc-bluetooth-adapter-at-a-time    This suggest that 4-7 devices can be connected at once per adapter depending on certain coniditions and limitations.

Comment: How many concurrently active bluetooth device do you want have?